# How to get data from 3 tables connected with a pivot in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pivot, pivot-table, laravel-7

I faced an issue where I'm unable to retrieve data through the pivot table,

In my application there's a separate table to store the files data and a separate table to store the competition and a separate table to store the teams.

And there's a table named `competition_file` which has the `competition_id, team_id, file_id`.

[image]

a user can add multiple files to a competition by selecting a team or by not selecting a team as show in the below image

[image]

It will be synced to the `competition_file` table as shown in the below image

[image]

I need to show all data in the UI as a table  shown in below image

[image]

I'm wondering how can I fill the `team name` selected using the pivot table

Relationship in `File Model`

```
 public function teams()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class,'competition_file')->wherePivot('type','document');
}
```

Relationship in `Competition Model`

```
    public function documents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(File::class,'competition_file','competition_id', 'file_id')->wherePivot('type','document');
}
```

And this is my `controller index` function

```
 public function index($id)
    {
        $competition = $this->competitionsRepo->find($id,[
            'team',
            'documents',
        ]);

        return view('competitions.document',[
          
            'competition'=>$competition,
        ]);
    }
```

My Blade

```
    @foreach ($competition->documents as $key=>$document)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $key+1 }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $document->name }}</td>
                                    <td>-</td>
                                    <td>{{ $document->created_at->toDateString() }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <form class="confirm" action="{{ route('documents.destroy',['competition'=>$competition,'document'=> $document->id]) }}" method="POST"
                                            data-confirm-title="Remove Document?"
                                            data-confirm-message="Are you sure you want to remove this document?">
                                            @csrf
                                            @method('DELETE')

                                            <button type="submit" name="button" class="button">Remove</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
   @endforeach
```

Someone please help me out to get the team names to my foreach in the blade

I hope my question is clear, please comment if it isn't ill edit the question

Comment: Do you only have a single UI that you have posted above for inserting data on teams, competitions, files and competiontion_file ? I am asking this because if you have different UI I need to think your question in different way.

Comment: @RameshKC No i have a different UI to create a competition and after creating a competition only we can add teams to the competition, and add files to the competition by selecting a team or by not selecting a team.

Comment: Jareer, foreach ($competition->documents as $key=>$document) , here a competition has many documents so $document will give you result in array of collection, so to display team name you may need to use another loop. You cannot directly use $document->teams->name.

Comment: @RameshKC I have added an answer below, anyway thanks for  your time, it was my fault that I didn't know `Eager Loading ` in Laravel, i had to learn it and i was able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue by learning Eager loading through a recommendation

Here are the changes I did

In `controller`

```
public function index($id)
    {
        $competition = $this->competitionsRepo->findOrFail($id);

        $files = $competition->documents()->with(
            [
                'teams' => function($q) use ($competition) {
                    $q->with([
                        'documents' => function($q) use($competition) {
                            $q->where([
                                'competition_id' => $competition->id,
                            ]);
                        }
                    ]);
                },
            ]
        )->get();

        return view('competitions.document',[
            'id'=>$id,
            'competition'=>$competition,
            'files'=>$files,
        ]);

    }
```

In my `Blade` table  i used  `$file->teams->implode('name')`

```
  <table class="table light-td sports-tbl tb-chg2 table-condensed table-borderless">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Document Name</th>
                                <th>Assigned Team</th>
                                <th>Date Added</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                              @foreach ($files as $key=>$file)
                              <tr>
                                <td>{{ $key+1 }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{{ asset('storage/'. $file->file_path) }}" class="text-info" target="_blank">
                                        <img src="{{ asset('/images/sketches/1x/file.png') }}" alt="file">
                                    </a>
                                    {{ $file->name }}
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    {!! $file->teams->isNotEmpty() ? $file->teams->implode('name') : '<span class="text-secondary">No teams selected</span>' !!}
                                </td>
                                <td>{{ $file->created_at->toDateString() }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <form class="confirm" action="{{ route('documents.destroy',['competition'=>$id,'document'=> $file->id]) }}" method="POST"
                                        data-confirm-title="Remove Document?"
                                        data-confirm-message="Are you sure you want to remove this document?">
                                        @csrf
                                        @method('DELETE')

                                        <button type="submit" name="button" class="button">Remove</button>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              @endforeach
                        </tbody>
 </table>
```